# Getting post type field from post object in repeater ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have searched for this, but I just can't find the right answer.
I have a repeater field named 'other_clients'. This repeater field contains a post object field named 'clients'. This post object field redirects to the post type named 'Klanten'. From the post type Klanten, it needs to obtain the field named 'klanten_image'. Here is my code:

```
<?php if( have_rows('other_clients') ): ?>

        <?php while ( have_rows('other_clients') ) : the_row(); ?>   
                <?php $post_object = get_sub_field('client'); ?>

                <?php if( $post_object ): ?>

                    <?php $post = $post_object; setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

                    <img src="<?php get_field('klanten_name') ?>" width="50" height="50" />

                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

If I use `get_title()`, it works and I get the titles of the posts of the post type 'Klanten'. But if I use the field named 'klanten_image' to get the logo of this client, it returns null.

Comment: Becasue `get_field()` returns value, without `echo`-ed it, what if you try to echo `<?php echo get_field('klanten_name') ?>`, or if you use `the_field()` function ? Or if you try to get raw object from Db, like function tutorial advice `$image = get_field('klanten_name', false, false);`

Comment: You can add the `$post->ID` to make sure you get the field from the right place.
`<img src="<?php echo get_field('klanten_name', $post->ID) ?>" width="50" height="50" />`